# Verify that the relationship is metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f$, $g$ be continuous functions on the interval $[0, 1]$, I want to verify if the following relation is metric

$$d_{0}(f, g)=\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)-g(t)|^2 \, dt$$

I have my doubts with the triangular inequality, since

$$d_{0}(f, g)=\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)-g(t)|^2 \, dt=\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)+h(t)-h(t)-g(t)|^2 \, dt= \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)-h(t)+h(t)-g(t)|^2 \, dt$$
I really doubt that I can deduce the triangular inequality from the latter, any suggestions?

Comment: It should be $$d(f,g) = \left\{\int \lvert f-g\rvert^2\right\}^{1/2}$$Then it will be a metric.

Comment: Yeah, this wouldn't be a metric - the equivalent definition on $\mathbb R^n$ would be $\sum |x_i-y_i|^2,$ which is the square of the traditional Euclidean metric, and the square of the metric is probably not a metric. You need to take the square root of this value.